# Oracle Apex Shoot email when approvers approve an issue using triggers and apex mail

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql, oracle-apex

I am developing oracle apex app where currently when issue is raised it sends email to all approvers who are Approver 1 in the particular issue dept.
After this, only when both approvers select Approve_This ='Y'  in application, then next email should go to the people with Approver=2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Don't do that.

See also this post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4330608

Recap:

- only send emails on committed data
- use a queuing system to send emails
- do it as a separate step from your DML

  - use a TAPI
  - 2nd Process step in APEX

## Workflow

What you are describing in this post is a Workflow.

You need to keep the logic of your Workflow separate from the data that holds a widget's state.

"Sending an email" is the action that is taken when the state of a widget changes.  You should keep that separate from the Workflow logic and the data table. (ie don't put it in a trigger)

Use Advance Queuing (AQ) to perform actions AFTER commit.

## Build vs. Buy

This is going to get complicated very fast.  I suggest you look at acquiring ($$) an already existing Workflow system with APEX interface for graphically building the Workflow.

Comment: I need help with second trigger as this needs to be done temporarily.  Please suggest the trigger solution for the time being. This will be rebuilt from scratch on larger basis later on

Comment: @Vini -  I have yet to see a "temporary code fix".  Your schema seems wrong.  Your `APPROVE_THIS` information should probably be a child table since it has a "1 to many" relationship. Also, you'll probably want to record extra information like WHO approved it and WHEN (maybe even WHY it was rejected).  I suggest you take the time to write it correctly (or buy the solution if time is more important than money)

Comment: Where can i find such a system "I suggest you look at acquiring ($$) an already existing Workflow system with APEX interface for graphically building the Workflow."?

Comment: @Vini - [Google](https://lmgtfy.com/?q=workflow+oracle+apex).  Beyond that, "List of software" questions are "off topic" for this site.

Comment: I mostly disagree with Michael's answer. 1) He's right about not using a trigger. You should just use an on submit page process for this. 2) Once you move to a page process, you don't need to worry about commits or queues. APEX uses a table behind the scenes and sends only committed rows via a background job. If your transaction is rolled back, the email is too. There's no need to use AQ for something this trivial. 3) This may or may not get complicated. Perhaps it will never change. Start with what works and is simple - there no need to buy anything given the current requirements.